# ¿Como preguntar con un if si nadie gana al tres en raya?

Tags: java

He desarrollado un programa con el [juego del gato (también llamado tic-tac-toe o trés en línea)](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tres_en_l%C3%ADnea) pero solo tengo declaradas las formas de ganar, pero no sé cómo preguntar o poner un `if` donde diga que nadie ganó.

Éste es mi código:

```
package gato;

import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Gato extends JFrame implements ActionListener{

    JButton iniciar = new JButton("Iniciar Juego.");
    JButton tablero [][];
    JLabel fondo;
    String jugador1,jugador2;
    int turno=-1;
    JLabel mensaje = new JLabel("Bienvenidos al Juego.");
    JLabel mensaje1 = new JLabel();
    Color colorB;

    public Gato() {

        this.setLayout(null);
        mensaje.setBounds(100, 20, 400, 30);
        mensaje.setFont(new Font("GARAGE IMPERIO", Font.PLAIN, 20));
        mensaje.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
        this.add(mensaje);
        mensaje1.setBounds(150, 60, 500, 30);
        mensaje1.setFont(new Font("GARAGE IMPERIO", Font.PLAIN, 20));
        mensaje1.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
        this.add(mensaje1);
        iniciar.setBounds(125, 400,150,30);
        iniciar.addActionListener(this);
        this.add(iniciar);
        tablero = new JButton [3][3];
        for(int i=0 ; i< 3 ; i++) {
            for(int j=0 ; j< 3 ; j++) {
                tablero[i][j] = new JButton();
                tablero[i][j].setBounds((i+1)*80,(j+1)*80,80,80);
                this.add(tablero[i][j]);
                tablero[i][j].addActionListener(this);
            }
        }
        colorB = tablero[0][0].getBackground();

        fondo = new JLabel();
        fondo.setSize(400, 500);
        fondo.setIcon(new ImageIcon("src/img/fondo.jpg"));
        fondo.setVisible(true);
        add(fondo);

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Gato ventana = new Gato();
        ventana.setDefaultCloseOperation(3);
        ventana.setSize(400, 500);
        ventana.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        ventana.setResizable(false);
        ventana.setTitle("JUEGO DEL GATO");
        ventana.setVisible(true);

    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if(e.getSource()==iniciar) {
            turno = 0;
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Iniciando el juego");
            jugador1 =JOptionPane.showInputDialog(this,"Escribe el nombre del 1°er jugador");
            jugador2 =JOptionPane.showInputDialog(this,"Escribe el nombre del 2°do jugador");
            mensaje.setText("Turno del jugador :" + jugador1);
            limpiar();
        }else {
            JButton boton = (JButton) e.getSource();
            if(turno == 0) {
                if(boton.getText().equals("")) {
                    boton.setBackground(Color.cyan);
                    boton.setFont(new Font("STENCIL", Font.PLAIN, 40));
                    boton.setText("X");
                    boton.setEnabled(false);
                    turno = 1;
                    mensaje.setText("Turno del jugador: " + jugador2);
                    mensaje1.setText("Sigue O");

                }
            }else {
                if(turno == 1) {
                    if(boton.getText().equals("")) {
                        boton.setBackground(Color.blue);
                        boton.setText("O");
                        boton.setFont(new Font("STENCIL", Font.PLAIN, 40));
                        boton.setEnabled(false);
                        turno = 0;
                        mensaje.setText("Turno del jugador: " + jugador1);
                        mensaje1.setText("Sigue X");
                    }
                }
            }
            verificar();
        }
    }

    public void verificar() {
        int ganador = 0;
        for(int i=0 ; i< 3 ; i++) {
            if(tablero[0][i].getText().equals("X") && tablero[1][i].getText().equals("X") && tablero[2][i].getText().equals("X")){

                ganador=1;

                if(ganador==1) {

                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this,"FELICIDADES JUGADOR " + jugador1 + " HAZ GANADO");

                }
            }

            if(tablero[i][0].getText().equals("X") && tablero[i][1].getText().equals("X") && tablero[i][2].getText().equals("X")){

                ganador=1;

                if(ganador==1) {

                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this,"FELICIDADES JUGADOR " + jugador1 + " HAZ GANADO");

                }
            }
            if(tablero[0][0].getText().equals("X") && tablero[1][1].getText().equals("X") && tablero[2][2].getText().equals("X")){

                ganador=1;

                if(ganador==1) {

                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this,"FELICIDADES JUGADOR " + jugador1 + " HAZ GANADO");

                }
            }
            if(tablero[0][2].getText().equals("X") && tablero[1][1].getText().equals("X") && tablero[2][0].getText().equals("X")){

                ganador=1;

                if(ganador==1) {

                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this,"FELICIDADES JUGADOR " + jugador1 + " HAZ GANADO");

                }
            }
            if(tablero[0][2].getText().equals("X") && tablero[1][1].getText().equals("X") && tablero[2][0].getText().equals("X")){

                ganador=1;

                if(ganador==1) {

                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this,"EMPATE");

                }
            }

        for(int j=0 ; j< 3 ; j++) {
            if(tablero[0][j].getText().equals("O") && tablero[1][j].getText().equals("O") && tablero[2][j].getText().equals("O")){

                ganador=2;

                if(ganador==2) {

                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this,"FELICIDADES JUGADOR " + jugador2 + " HAZ GANADO");

                }
            }
            if(tablero[j][0].getText().equals("O") && tablero[j][1].getText().equals("O") && tablero[j][2].getText().equals("O")){

                ganador=2;

                if(ganador==2) {

                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this,"FELICIDADES JUGADOR " + jugador2 + " HAZ GANADO");

                }
            }
            if(tablero[0][0].getText().equals("O") && tablero[1][1].getText().equals("O") && tablero[2][2].getText().equals("O")){

                ganador=2;

                if(ganador==2) {

                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this,"FELICIDADES JUGADOR " + jugador2 + " HAZ GANADO");

                }
            }
            if(tablero[0][2].getText().equals("O") && tablero[1][1].getText().equals("O") && tablero[2][0].getText().equals("O")){

                ganador=2;
                }

                if(ganador==1) {

                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this,"FELICIDADES JUGADOR " + jugador1 + " HAZ GANADO");
                    bloquear();
                }
                if(ganador==2) {

                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this,"FELICIDADES JUGADOR " + jugador2 + " HAZ GANADO");
                    bloquear();
                    }
                }
            }
        }

    public void bloquear() {
        for(int i=0 ; i< 3 ; i++) {
            for(int j=0 ; j< 3 ; j++) {
                tablero[i][j].setEnabled(false);
            }
        }
    }
    public void limpiar() {
        for(int i=0 ; i< 3 ; i++) {
            for(int j=0 ; j< 3 ; j++) {
                tablero[i][j].setEnabled(true);
                tablero[i][j].setText("");
                tablero[i][j].setBackground(colorB);

            }
        }   
    }
}
```

Comment: Suponiendo que lo estamos guardando en la variable `ganador`, podríamos hacer algo tal que así -`if(ganador!=1 && ganador!=2) {                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this,"EMPATE");`

Comment: Cada vez que se rellena un espacio, comprueba que no haya ganador, si no hay ganador compruebaque no queden huecos libres y si no hay ganador ni huecos libres saca el mensaje de empate